# How to mock logging.config.distConfig with a config dict that contains non-trivial objects?

Tags: python, testing, mocking

Please consider the following code :

```py
# application/utils.py
import logging
from io import StringIO

def setup_logging(conf=None):
    if conf is None:
        config = {
            "version": 1,
            "disable_existing_loggers": False,
            "incremental": False,
            "formatters": {
                "standard": {
                    "format": "[%(threadName)s] %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s",
                    "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                }
            },
            "handlers": {
                "console": {
                    "level": "INFO",
                    "formatter": "standard",
                    "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                    "stream": StringIO(),
                }
            },
            "root": {"handlers": ["console"], "level": "INFO"},
            "loggers": {
                "py4j.java_gateway": {"level": "ERROR"},
                "botocore": {"level": "ERROR"},
                "boto3": {"level": "ERROR"},
                "s3transfer": {"level": "ERROR"},
                "urllib3": {"level": "ERROR"},
            },
        }
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)
   else:
       # some code based on reading a config file...
```

```py
# test_setup_logging.py
from io import StringIO
from unittest import mock
from application.utils import setup_logging

@mock.patch("logging.config.dictConfig")
def test_setup_logging(mock_logging_config):
    
    expected_conf_dict = {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "incremental": False,
        "formatters": {
            "standard": {
                "format": "[%(threadName)s] %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s",
                "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
            }
        },
        "handlers": {
            "console": {
                "level": "INFO",
                "formatter": "standard",
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "stream": StringIO(),
            }
        },
        "root": {"handlers": ["console"], "level": "INFO"},
        "loggers": {
            "py4j.java_gateway": {"level": "ERROR"},
            "botocore": {"level": "ERROR"},
            "boto3": {"level": "ERROR"},
            "s3transfer": {"level": "ERROR"},
            "urllib3": {"level": "ERROR"},
        },
    }

    setup_logging()
    mock_logging_config.assert_called_once_with(expected_conf_dict)
```

The test will fail as `io.StringIO` is a class that does not seem to implement `__eq__`. As a result, if you do the following comparison, it will fail :

```py
>>> s1=StringIO()
>>> s2=StringIO()
>>> assert s1==s2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

My idea was to find the config dict passed to `logging.config.dictConfig` and then performdo a simple comparison like that :

```py
d1 = {"key1":"foo", "key2":StringIO(), ...}
d2 = {"key1":"foo", "key2":StringIO(), ...}
for k, v1 in d1.items():
    if k == "key2":
         assert isinstance(v1, StringIO) and isinstance(d2[k], StringIO)
    else:
         assert v1 == d2[k]
```

However, it seems that `logging.config.dictConfig` does not store the config dict in the current logger (root logger here).

Can someone help me to solve it ? Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks.

Comment: 1. StringIO cannot implement eq because it's a stream - two streams are not equal unless they're literally the same object. 2. And yes, logger does not store the dictConfig - it parses it and just configures everything based on that. So you'd just have to e.g. get those loggers and check their levels, get the handler and check its type... etc

Comment: That makes this test too long to code.. Well, I will avoid loosing too much time for this. Thank you.